# Repair Table After Server Upgrade

Tags: database, nodes

Hello i hope someone can help me with this on here as [i posted on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1428064#comment-5562210) and folks told me it wasnt a drupal issue. I dont mind learning stuff but ive got so much drupal things that i do know about to get on with to get my site open that i dont want to spend a week trying to learn more about databases. All help appreciated. thanks.

My hosting company upgraded their servers the other now. Now my statistics module is all messed up and it's asking me to repair a table. The error message is-

> User warning: Table './onlineba_d939/node_counter' is marked
>   as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT totalcount, daycount,
>   timestamp FROM node_counter WHERE nid = 4389 in _db_query() (line 148
>   of /home/onlineba/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc).

and

> User warning: Table './onlineba_d939/node_counter' is marked
>   as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT node.nid AS nid,
>   node.title AS node_title, node_counter.totalcount AS
>   node_counter_totalcount FROM node node LEFT JOIN og_ancestry
>   og_ancestry ON node.nid = og_ancestry.nid LEFT JOIN node
>   node_og_ancestry ON og_ancestry.group_nid = node_og_ancestry.nid LEFT
>   JOIN og_uid og_uid ON node.nid = og_uid.nid LEFT JOIN node_counter
>   node_counter ON node.nid = node_counter.nid WHERE (node.status = 1)
>   AND (og_uid.uid = 1) ORDER BY node_counter_totalcount DESC LIMIT 0, 10
>   in _db_query() (line 148 of
>   /home/onlineba/public_html/includes/database.mysql.inc).

I have access to PHPmyadmin and i have a very very basic understanding of it. Is there a line of code or query i need to put in it to repair? I should go look maybe there is just a repair button. I think i saw that before. Anyone offer me any help before i destroy everything?

thanks

Comment: Managed to get an answer over by. Soz. I just wanted it to be sorted. The answer is

The table's name is node_counter. The statement then becomes.

REPAIR TABLE node_counter;

Nice and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have PHPMyAdmin, you should be able to fix this with some point and clicking.

1. Navigate to the node_counter in your Drupal database
2. Go to the 'Operations' tab
3. Hit check tables
4. If something isn't right it should give you the option to repair

If the option to repair doesn't come up and it doesn't appear in the Operations tab (some of these move around version to version of PHPMyAdmin), you can run the command

```
REPAIR TABLE node_counter;
```

from the SQL tab.

Good luck!